# Shap beeswarm plot: Colour criterion for regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, plotly, regression, shap

Back in the day, I came up with the following code to export a Shap beeswarm as an interactive HTML file using Plotly:

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(best_model.predict, X_test)
shap_values = explainer(X_test)

shap_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.c_[shap_values.base_values, shap_values.values],
    columns = ['Shap_Base'] + list(X_test.columns)
)

shap_df.drop('Shap_Base', axis=1, inplace=True)

values = shap_df.iloc[:,2:].abs().mean(axis=0).sort_values().index
df_plot = pd.melt(shap_df, id_vars=['transaction_id', 'predictions'], value_vars=values, var_name='Feature', value_name='SHAP')

fig = px.strip(df_plot, x='SHAP', y='Feature', color='predictions', stripmode='overlay', height=4000, width=1000, hover_data=['transaction_id', df_plot.index])
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(showgrid=True, gridcolor='WhiteSmoke', zerolinecolor='Gainsboro'),
              yaxis=dict(showgrid=True, gridcolor='WhiteSmoke', zerolinecolor='Gainsboro')
)
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='white')
fig.update_layout(boxgap=0)
fig.update_traces(jitter=1)
fig.write_html('beeswarm.html')
```

There I was colouring by Feature which was a binary label.

However now I am working on a regression problem.

Would there be a simple way of setting the colour on a similar way?

How do I extract that information from the shap values?

Comment: Is this the relevant chunk of code:
```
features = shap_exp.data
if sp.sparse.issparse(features):
 features = features.toarray()

# default color:
if color is None:
 if features is not None:
  color = colors.red_blue
 else:
  color = colors.blue_rgb
```
If it is not, could someone please point me to the right function?

If it is, features is a matrix. What is that if evaluating?

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was deleted. Essentially you need to bin the features. Something like this:

```
for col in data_df.columns:
        mean = data_df[col].mean()
        data_df[col] = data_df[col].apply(lambda x: 'blue' if x < mean else 'red')
```

Then you define your map:

```
color_discrete_map = {'blue': '#0097c7', 'red': '#eb3e00'}
```

And you plot it like:

```
fig_featimp = px.strip(df_plot, x='SHAP', y='Feature', stripmode='overlay', color='value', color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map, 
                height=1860, width=900, hover_data=['account'])
```

Going from data_df to df_plot is a bit tricky and is beyond the scope of this question.